# Issue playing audio with AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift2, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

Current code:

```
@IBAction func sound1(sender: UIButton)
{
    var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sound1", ofType: "wav")!)

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }

    var error: NSError?
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.volume = 1
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

This is the current code I had before updating this project to Swift 2.

```
audioPlayer = nil
```

The issue I get when trying to run the app is this:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'NilLiteralConvertible' to a value of type 'AVAudioPlayer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your variable `audioplayer` is not an Optional and so can not be set to `nil`.

Either make it an Optional then use it with `try?` *(note the `?`)* without `do catch`, or do not attempt to set it to `nil` if you want to continue using `try` inside `do catch`.